# multicollinearity in OLS regression

Tags: least-squares, multicollinearity

If I have a dependent variable Y and two independent variables X1 and X2 , that are highly correlated.

Y ~ beta1*X1 + beta2*X2

What issues can multicollinearity cause in an OLS regression, apart from unstable beta1 and beta2 estimates ?

Comment: What would it mean for the $R^2$ to be "higher than it should be"?

Comment: removed that part of the question. It was an ambiguous statement.

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe: I thought about it too, but that one seems to pertain specifically to parameter estimates, and this one specifically **not** to them.

Comment: If you have high multi-collinearity, your beta1 and beta2 are essentially meaningless, you cannot trust their statistically significance nor magnitude. Your R-squared is inflated, so it is largely meaningless. There is no useful information that the regression provides, what other issues could there be?